# Exposing a custom getter in a Response DTO does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-transformer

I've tried to define a custom getter like this:

```
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';

export class MyDTOResponse {
  @Expose()
  id: string;

  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  get thisIsATest(): string {
    return 'yolo';
  }
}
```

This is how I transform it:

```
plainToClass(MyDTOResponse, MyRawDataObject, {
  excludeExtraneousValues: true,
});
```

As described in the documentation here: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#exposing-getters-and-method-return-values

However, the response is only:

```
{
  "id": "f8c213c7-5853-4d01-b424-cb0349a6c580",
  "name": "Clean the kitchen!"
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong exactly, but I am missing the "thisIsATest" property.

Answer (score 1):

`plainToClass` will return an instance. If you `console.log` this instance, you can't see the "thisIsATest" property. You can try the following code:

```
const res = plainToClass(MyDTOResponse, MyRawDataObject, {
  excludeExtraneousValues: true,
});

console.log(res.thisIsATest); // yolo

console.log(instanceToPlain(res))
// {
//   id: 'f8c213c7-5853-4d01-b424-cb0349a6c580',
//   name: 'Clean the kitchen!',
//   thisIsATest: 'yolo'
// }
```

Btw, `plainToClass` is deprecated, use the `plainToInstance` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Transform` decorator for this, and remove the getter,

something like this

```
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';

export class MyDTOResponse {
  @Expose()
  id: string;

  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  @Transform(({ value, key, obj, type }) => 'yolo' )
  thisIsATest: string

  @Expose()
  @Transform(({ value, key, obj, type }) => obj.name )
  thisIsATestB: string
}
```

for more information you can check the below link

[advance use of transform](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#advanced-usage)